# How to avoid clearing cache each time there is some modifications on js file

Tags: jquery

I am using j-query for the client side activities.

But after any modification on js file, when I am trying to run the application,the new functionalities are not working.

Then I need to refresh (ctrl + F5) the browser to make it work.

This is fine at the time of testing at local but when the same modifications pushed to
live server, their also the same problem occurs.

And I can't force my users to refresh and clear their cache each time after any modification.

So any work around to get rid of this problem ?

Comment: Is caching enabled on your browser?

Comment: either use the e-tag/modified since cache headers... or use a version number in path

Comment: Disable caching on your development server. Remember to turn it back on before going live though - assuming it's the same server.

Comment: The client's browser should check for this periodically on its own. Downloaded files aren't cached forever by the browser. If the changes you're making involve major functionality changes, you might add a version number to the file name itself. If they don't, you can probably allow clients to use the old cached version for a short time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should append the version number (or an incrementing number) to the deployed script. Then increment the number when you release a new version of the file and the browser will reload the file.

So you would have `<script src=yourscript-1.js></script>` for the first version, and `<script src=yourscript-2.js></script>` for the second, and so on.

As a bonus, people may be able to report bugs in a specific version of the js, which should aid in bugfinding.

Answer (score 1):

Randomize the source of the file

```
<script src="yourscript.js?123"></script>
```

JS solution:

```
<script>
     document.write('<script src="yourscript.js?'+Math.random()+'"></script>');
</script>
```

Or use the serverside language (asp.net in this case):

```
<script src="yourscript.js?<%= GetApplicationVersion() %>"></script>
```

You get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh page using this jQuery Script.

`reload()` is supposed to accept an argument which tells it to do a hard reload, ie, ignoring the cache:

```
location.reload(true);
```

or use

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a parameter to included file should work.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js?v=1"></script>
```

You can do it manually, or write a little script that adds it automatically.

Comment: Since the parameter is always 1, when the browser looks at this file, doesn't it use the one in the cache instead of the new one because the javascript file with parameter 1 is available in the cache?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Django`, you can use [`django-compressor`](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/).
It both compresses your code and generates a random file name.

Snippet from the documentation:

```
{% load compress %}

{% compress js %}
<script src="/static/js/one.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">obj.value = "value";</script>
{% endcompress %}
```

would be rendered something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/CACHE/js/3f33b9146e12.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```